# User logged out when TV is turned off and on again

Tags: gnome, hdmi, tv

A computer running Ubuntu 17.10 and Gnome is connected to a single monitor (Sony Bravia TV) via HDMI. While logged in with applications open if the TV is turned off and back on again the user will be logged out. Once logged back in to the same account all applications are closed.

I can continue to run commands via SSH while the TV is off/user is logged out so the computer is still awake.

All power management settings are disabled in the Gnome settings manager. If the TV is left on the computer will stay logged in indefinitely.

I have also tried disabling all related TV settings including "Power off HDMI devices with the TV".

Below are the logs from `journalctl`. When the TV is powered off nothing changes, the below are from immediately after the TV is powered back on. It appears that `gnome-shell` is crashing but how do I work out what is causing the issue?

```
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-shell[3355]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x557d6a2b4db0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] connect method
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-shell[3355]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x557d6a2b4db0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] disconnect method
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-shell[3355]: WARNING: addSignalMethods is replacing existing [0x557d6a2b4db0 Gjs_ShowAppsIcon.dash-item-container] emit method
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini kernel: [ 2081.251322] gnome-shell[3355]: segfault at d0000021b ip 00007fc4e88cb233 sp 00007fff175dc828 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7fc4e88c8000+d000]
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini update-notifier[3643]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini qbittorrent[3597]: Error reading events from display: Broken pipe
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3355]: (EE)
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3355]: Fatal server error:
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3355]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Connection reset by peer
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3355]: (EE)
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-session-binary[3324]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-session-binary[3324]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Feb  5 19:04:48 mini gnome-session[3324]: gnome-session-binary[3324]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue traced to `gdm`. Installing `lightdm` seems to fix.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Suggestion found in this bug report[1]

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1714908